# Version error in IntelliJ Idea while using the Android support Plugin

Tags: android, intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-plugin

So I was testing my Android App Build. (In IntelliJ IDEA **2021.2**)
While starting the sync, an error popped up in the build...

The error was that "The version of the IDE was below 2020.3.1" 
But I am using **IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2**

Please help me find the real problem or suggest anything.
OUTPUT ON THE CONSOLE:

`This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2020.3.1 or newer.`

Comment: Update the plugin manually in settings.